# retrofit @Body converts the given body data as array

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am using retrofit2 for network calls in my project. For a post method I need to pass request body data. So decided to use @Body annotation. This converts the given Gson.JsonObject to Array like below mentioned.
Retrofit dependencies used

```
//retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.7.2'
```

Expected

```
 {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": value3
}
```

But got converted like

```
[{

      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": value3
    }]
```

This is my API service call

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("Account/LoginAsync")
fun doLogin(@Body payLoad: JsonObject): Call<JsonObject>
```

And data class is

```
data class LoginRequest(
    val email: String,
    val password: String,
    val rememberMe: Boolean
)
```

Internally what I am doing is

From the specified values in LoginRequest generating org.json.JSONObject like below

```
private fun generateLoginPayload(
    email: String,
    password: String,
    rememberMe: Boolean
): JSONObject {
    return JSONObject().apply {
        put(LOGIN_EMAIL, email)
        put(LOGIN_PASSWORD, password)
        put(LOGIN_REMEMBER_ME, rememberMe)
    }

}
```

And then

```
val payload = generateLoginPayload(email, password, rememberMe)
val requestCall = ApiService.create()
    .doLogin(JsonParser().parse(payload.toString()) as JsonObject)
```

After enqueuing the request call got error response as 400 (bad request).

I have checked from the debug values.
What is the possible reason for it ?

Comment: You got json Array instead of json object .Share us model class.

Comment: @Karthikeyan Please share the the kotlin `data` class or Java `POJO` you're using as the json request body.

Comment: @TobiDaada Added the required details.

Answer (score 0):

##### Solution 1

If you're trying to send a json payload containing the email, password, and rememberMe option to the `Account/LoginAsync` endpoint you don't need the `generateLoginPayload` function.

First, refactor your API service function to something like this:

```kotlin
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("Account/LoginAsync")
fun doLogin(@Body payLoad: LoginRequest): Call<JSONObject>
```

Then update the payload

```kotlin
val payload = LoginRequest(email, password, rememberMe)
val requestCall = ApiService.create().doLogin(payload)
```

##### Solution 2

If you really want to use the `JSONObject` object in the request body there's no need to convert the `payload` object to a string, only to later use your `JsonParser` to convert it back to `JSONObject`. Just update the last part of the code to:

```kotlin
val payload = generateLoginPayload(email, password, rememberMe)
val requestCall = ApiService.create().doLogin(payload)
```

---

I'm not familiar with the `JsonParser` object. If it's a custom class, please also include the body of the `parse` method so we can inspect it (if the above solutions don't work).